# xml parser using flex/bison space,comments not working

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, bison, flex-lexer

as part of a school project I'm tasked with creating an xml parser using flex/bison. (not every aspect of xml, just some basics). Here's my code for both flex and bison.
Here's my flex code (parts of it) :

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int lineNumber = 1;
%}
%option noyywrap
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
other_characters [./_-]
whitespace [ \t]
newline [\n]
string ({letter}|{digit}|{other_characters})({letter}|{digit}|{other_characters})+
%%
"ss:Workbook"       {printf("%s", yytext); return WORKBOOK;}
"ss:Styles"     {printf("%s", yytext); return STYLES;}
"\/ss:Style"        {printf("%s", yytext); return CLOSINGSTYLE;}
"ss:Style"      {printf("%s", yytext); return STYLE;}
"<"     {printf("%s", yytext); return START;}
">"     {printf("%s", yytext); return CLOSE;}
"/"     {printf("%s", yytext); return SLASH;} 
{string}({whitespace}|{string})*    {printf ("%s", yytext); return KEIMENO;}
"ss:ID\="\"{string}\"       {printf("%s", yytext); return ID;}
{whitespace}        {printf(" "); } /* This is to deal with whitespaces */
{newline}       {printf("\n");lineNumber++; } /*Counting line*/
"<!--"[^-]*"-->"        {printf("%s",yytext); } /* this is to deal with comments */
%%
```

and here's my bison code(parts of it) :

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int errorCount = 0; 
extern int lineNumber;
int yylex();
void yyerror(char *);
extern FILE *yyin;
extern FILE *yyout;
%}
%start WorkbookElement
%token KEIMENO
%token WORKBOOK
%token STYLES
%token STYLE
%token CLOSINGSTYLE
%token START
%token CLOSE
%token SLASH
%token ID
%%
text : KEIMENO | ;
StyleElement : START STYLE ID CLOSE START SLASH STYLE CLOSE ;
Stylescontext : text StyleElement text ;
StylesElement : START STYLES CLOSE Stylescontext START CLOSINGSTYLE CLOSE | START STYLES SLASH CLOSE | START STYLES CLOSE text START SLASH STYLES CLOSE ;
Workbookcontext : text StylesElement text ; 
WorkbookElement : START WORKBOOK CLOSE Workbookcontext START SLASH WORKBOOK CLOSE | START WORKBOOK SLASH CLOSE ;
%%
void yyerror (char *s)
{
    errorCount++;
    fprintf(stderr,"%s on line %d \n",s,lineNumber); /*here I get the info about errors */
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    } else {
        yyin = stdin;
    }

    int result;

    if ((result = yyparse()) == 0) {   
        printf("No syntax errors\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nFound %d syntax errors\n",errorCount);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now my problem is that while this compiles (with some minor issues like rule useless due to conflict) when I test it on a simple xml file it finds errors that are not supposed to exit. for example I've used the parser on the following xml file :

```
<ss:Workbook>
     <ss:Styles>
         <ss:Style ss:ID=”s123”></ss:Style>
         <ss:Style ss:ID=”x123”></ss:Style>
     </ss:Styles>
</ss:Workbook>
```

This file is supposed to be correct but nonetheless the parser finds a `syntax error on line 4 :

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: --(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 19 ("<")
Next token is token START ()
Shifting token START ()
Entering state 1
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 15 ("ss:Workbook")
Next token is token WORKBOOK ()
Shifting token WORKBOOK ()
Entering state 3
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 20 (">")
Next token is token CLOSE ()
Shifting token CLOSE ()
Entering state 5
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 25 ("
")
<ss:Workbook>
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 19 ("<")
Next token is token START ()
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 28):
-> $$ = nterm text ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5
Entering state 9
Next token is token START ()
Shifting token START ()
Entering state 12
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 18 ("ss:Styles")
Next token is token STYLES ()
Shifting token STYLES ()
Entering state 15
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 20 (">")
Next token is token CLOSE ()
Shifting token CLOSE ()
Entering state 18
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 25 ("
")
     <ss:Styles>
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 19 ("<")
Next token is token START ()
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 28):
-> $$ = nterm text ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18
Entering state 22
Next token is token START ()
Shifting token START ()
Entering state 25
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 16 ("ss:Style")
Next token is token STYLE ()
Shifting token STYLE ()
Entering state 28
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 23 ("ss:ID=”s123”")
Next token is token ID ()
Shifting token ID ()
Entering state 32
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 20 (">")
Next token is token CLOSE ()
Shifting token CLOSE ()
Entering state 35
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 19 ("<")
Next token is token START ()
Shifting token START ()
Entering state 37
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 17 ("/ss:Style")
Next token is token CLOSINGSTYLE ()
Shifting token CLOSINGSTYLE ()
Entering state 38
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 20 (">")
Next token is token CLOSE ()
Shifting token CLOSE ()
Entering state 39
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 23):
   $1 = token START ()
   $2 = token STYLE ()
   $3 = token ID ()
   $4 = token CLOSE ()
   $5 = token START ()
   $6 = token CLOSINGSTYLE ()
   $7 = token CLOSE ()
-> $$ = nterm StyleElement ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18 22
Entering state 26
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 25 ("
")
         <ss:Style ss:ID=”s123”></ss:Style>
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting default rule ("     ")
--accepting rule at line 24 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 19 ("<")
Next token is token START ()
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 28):
-> $$ = nterm text ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18 22 26
Entering state 30
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 24):
   $1 = nterm text ()
   $2 = nterm StyleElement ()
   $3 = nterm text ()
-> $$ = nterm Stylescontext ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18
Entering state 21
Next token is token START ()
Shifting token START ()
Entering state 24
Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 16 ("ss:Style")
Next token is token STYLE ()
syntax error on line 4
Error: popping token START ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18 21
Error: popping nterm Stylescontext ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15 18
Error: popping token CLOSE ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12 15
Error: popping token STYLES ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9 12
Error: popping token START ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5 9
Error: popping nterm text ()
Stack now 0 1 3 5
Error: popping token CLOSE ()
Stack now 0 1 3
Error: popping token WORKBOOK ()
Stack now 0 1
Error: popping token START ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token STYLE ()
Stack now 0
         <ss:Style
Found 1 syntax errors
```

I'm a beginner in both flex and bison so there are certain things I must have missed. From what I can understand there must be something wrong with the bison file. Any clues on what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `[^--]` means exactly the same thing as `[^-]`, because `[...]` is a *character class* (that is, a set of characters). Brackets do not surround a regular expression, and flex does not have any syntax which means "any sequence of characters which doesn't contain the sequence ...". That's hard to write in any regex library, and flex's regular expressions are really regular expressions. See https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html for documentation on Flex patterns and any good regex tutorial for more details.

Comment: Also: The error message you copied into your message includes the text of a token, I believe, and that does not correspond with the code you pasted, in which `yyerror` only prints the flex error message and line number. When pasting code and output/error messages, please always make sure that they correspond; that is, that the code produces precisely the error and/or output indicated, character for character. Otherwise, it's impossible for other people to make reliable deductions.

Comment: well I fixed the comments issues using "<!--"[^-]*"-->" after taking a closer look at the patterns. as to the other problem I'm currently running the parser with debug and trace to understand why it's ignoring whitespace

Comment: That regular expression is much clearer, but note that it is not quite correct; it won't let you use a single dash in a comment, for example. (Read up on start conditions in the Fkex manual to see how to construct a more precise solution.) Using the built-in trace features is an excellent way to debug your program and gain a better understanding of how the scanner and parser work. Goid luck!

Comment: edited the post to add the results of debugging

Comment: Clearly the rule at line 22 isn't matching ss:ID=”s123”. There's nothing wrong with the rule. Look really closely at the quotes in the input.

Comment: oh my god I've been struggling with that thing for 2 days now and now I've seen it, thank you !

Comment: got another problem since /ss:Style is recognized as "/ss" ":" and "Style" for some reason so I solved that with adding more rules/tokens. editing post again .

Comment: That's because `other_characters` includes `/` for some reason. Really, you should recognize `<` and `</` as different tokens (OPENTAG and CLOSETAG), but in general terms your design is flawed: you need at least two lexical contexts, one inside a tag and the other outside (i.e. text). Read up on start conditions.